# Installing several Windows instances on Virtualbox

Tags: windows, licensing, virtualbox

in Virtualbox it is possible to set up several instances of the same OS. Now I want to install Windows XP two or three times, because I need to check all my webwork on different Windows settings and IEs. Therefore I need to purchase one working license for the XP. But If I want to run three XPs (NOT simultaneously), do I need to have three licenses?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: If you did then you would be the first!

Comment: I just don’t want to install anything, my boss isn’t cool with. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your boss happy (not spending more money than needed) and the Microsoft company happy you may want to consider installing their VHD's:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef

You can load these with Virtualbox. In so doing no licence violations will have been committed.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for that quick answer. I guess that this is the best solution. But I can’t figure out how to load the *.exe with Virtualbox. Since I am working on a Mac I don’t know how to get these things rolling. So let me ask this question: I have to install Windows XP on the Virtualbox without using any license and there I run the VHD?

Comment: Found something: http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/creating-an-internet-explorer-testing-environment-on-a-mac/  I’ll try it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Also consider getting any old PC to run your test VMs. Put a linux distro on it and have your VMs 'headless' with remote desktop being how you get to them. In that way your machine is not going to be bogged down by 2+ VMs competing for memory, CPU etc. You can also access the remote desktop from your boss's machine if need be. This arrangement has worked really well where I work and the whole team uses the same VMs on remote desktop connections.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve tried to install a fully working Windows OS over the VM. It actually did work, but I was looking for something easier and slicker. I did find the [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) app in addition to the [Winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) app. These two work together perfectly for my needs: Installing IE 6, 7 and 8 for testing purposes. However I’ve had some issues installing IE6, but I think I will work it out soon. Use Wine to install Windows apps without having to run a full Windows partition. You just have to download the Winebottler, its image contains Wine already. You just have to Update Wine after running it the first time.

Thanks for your reply Mathew. I think your solution is also worth thinking about!

Best, Floyd Pepper